# Switch(Change) between two images on hitting refresh

Tags: php

I have a webpage and in that I want to change between two images on refreshing. I don't want to use random function because it will only produce a random output like, I may get the first image correctly, but the second image might be show after 8 or 9 refresh attempts. So using random function is not possible.

Comment: See my answer, this way the it will keep on showing the next image until the last then start over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the current image been displayed in a session variable:

```
session_start();

$total_images = 10; // or whatever is the total number of images u have

if (!isset($_SESSION['current'])){
   $_SESSION['current'] = 1;
   $current = 1;
}else {
   $current = $_SESSION['current'];
   $_SESSION['current']++;
}

if ($_SESSION['current'] > $total_images) {
   $_SESSION['current'] = 1; // this way it will start over it reaches the end
}

$image = "image/path/name{$current}.jpg"; // name1.jpg, name2.jpg ... and so on;

// now echo the current image
echo "<img src={$image} alt='' />";
```

Comment: +1 solution seems quite reasonable. However, the connection between `$_SESSION['current']` and `$current` seems a tad complicated when trying to understand that the roll over will indeed work as intended. I think it'd be much clearer to start with `$current = $_SESSION['current']` simply for brevity and only work with the one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet, simple and easy.

```
session_start();
$swap = 8; // or 9, depends on you
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
else {
     $_SESSION['count']++;
     if ($_SESSION['count'] < $swap) echo '<img src="image1.jpg" />';
     else {
        echo '<img src="image2.jpg" />';
        unset($_SESSION['count']);
     }
}
```